# Debounce a ng-model dict to catch changes in all keys

Tags: javascript, angularjs, debouncing

Consider next situation.
There is some form, `ng-model` of each input is a part of some dict (for example, `model = {firstName: '', lastName: ''}`).
There is a deep watch on this dictionary `model`, which detects if some of inner elements was changed, and then performs a request to API.

I'm using debounce of lodash to send only last input of a field:

```
$rootScope.$watch "model", _.debounce((newValue, oldValue) ->
  ...
, watchDebounceTime), true
```

but, the main problem of that approach is if user will type to fields very quickly, `model` will be debounced in way that it will detect only last field change (for example user types first name and then quickly types the last name, so first change will be ignored).

How it can be resolved to apply debounce to prevent request on each user type and allow to fill all fields quickly?

Comment: you may call the same function on `onblur` event, which you are calling inside your watch.

Comment: watch is a requirement, since I have many watches which are binding/unbinding when I need it

Comment: then keep watches and call the same function on `onblur` as well. I assume you are calling some function in your watch

Comment: this function is creating a diff of `newValue` and `oldValue` of watch, and I'm sending changed ones to API, so it can be applied only to watch. Also I  have many fields and it is hard to manage each field by adding `onBlur` to each field, when I can only bind a watch.

Comment: personally i would prefer doing this kind of stuff on `ng-change` of input fields. This would save lot of unnecessary function calls.